# Solve $10x + y =_3 x \wedge 10x+y =_5 y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

> Solve $10x + y =_3 x \wedge 10x+y =_5 y$

Task comes from concrete mathematics. 
This is my approach
 \begin{cases} 10x + y =_3 x \\ 10x+y =_5 y \end{cases}

\begin{cases} 50x + 5y =_{15} 5x \\ 30x+3y =_{15} 3y \end{cases} 
$$ 80x+8y =_{15} 5x + 3y $$
but I stucked there... how can it be continued?

in book they say that

> We want $10x+6y =_{15} 10x+y$ so...

but I don't know how they got this equality.

Comment: What do you mean with $=_6$? Is it modulo 6?

Comment: $a =_6 b $ if and only if $a \mod 6 = b \mod 6$

Comment: If it is modulo 6, then the second equation you are given is useless... $$10x=_5 0$$ so of course $$10x+y=_5 y$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $10x+y\equiv x\pmod 3$ then $y\equiv0\pmod 3$, so $3$ divides $y$ and therefore $5y$.

$5$ also divides $5y$.  Therefore $15$ divides $5y,$ so $10x+6y\equiv10x+y\pmod{15}$.

Comment: so $5y = y$ (mod 15)?

Comment: no, $5y\equiv0\pmod{15}$; $\color{blue}6y\equiv y\pmod{15}$

Comment: ok so $5y = 0$ (mod 15) then $y = 0 (mod 3)$ but in book there is result that $x =0$ or $x=1$ but from this equality I see that $x$ doesn't care there

Comment: yes, $y\equiv0\pmod3$, but, from the information you typed, I can't tell what $x$ is modulo $3$, but I don't need to since $10x$ is on both sides of the equation; for all $x$, $10x\equiv x\pmod3$ and $10x\equiv0\pmod5$

Comment: Ok but if we have $ 10x+y =_5 y $ why we can't tell that it is the same $10x + y =_5 0 + y$ so $ 10x  =_5 0 $?

Comment: and why you claim that if $ 10x+y\equiv x\pmod 3 $ then $y\equiv0\pmod 3$?

Comment: because $10x+y\equiv x+y\pmod3 [$ because $(9x\equiv0\pmod3)],$ so if $10x+y\equiv x$ then $y\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: Ok, I got that, but can you tell me why I have failed in that comment? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3212638/solve-10x-y-3-x-wedge-10xy-5-y/3212645?noredirect=1#comment6610130_3212645

Comment: For any $x, 10x\equiv0\pmod5,$ because $10x=5\times2x$ and $5\equiv0\pmod5$

Comment: now I understand! You have helped me a lot! Thanks!